# Acess 2007 Attachment type to SQL server

Tags: sql, ms-access, attachment, sql-server-2014

My predecessor created an Access database in 2007, which has a number of tables, forms and query.

One of the tables holds images, which are stored as attachments.

The database is almost 2GB in size (compacting and repairing doesn't change it). So I'd like to convert it to a SQL Server 2014 database.

I've used the Data Import tool, which has copied the tables & data into SQL Server. But the attachments are just converted to a string of their file name (`image1.jpg`)

Is there anyway to import the images from the MS Access database in to the SQL Server?

I also have a Sharepoint 2010 server, would this be a better option?

Update (sorry new to Stack Overflow, not sure what to put where)

I've changed the field mapping in import wizard to IMAGE, and I get the following error. If I set it to ignore, the fields are blank. using VARSTRING, puts either Null or 0x in the field.

> - Executing (Error) Messages Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Photos" (23) to column
>     "Photos" (57).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text
>     "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
>     data.".  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Data Conversion 0 -
>   0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Photos]" failed because error code 0xC020907F occurred, and the error row disposition on "Data
>   Conversion 0 - 0.Outputs[Data Conversion Output].Columns[Photos]"
>   specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object
>   of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before
>   this with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Data
>   Conversion 0 - 0" (49) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while
>   processing input "Data Conversion Input" (50). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server
>   Import and Export Wizard)   Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task 1: The
>   attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error
>   code 0xC0047020.  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   Error
>   0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.
>   The PrimeOutput method on Source - Attachments returned error code
>   0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline
>   engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is
>   defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline
>   stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this
>   with more information about the failure.  (SQL Server Import and
>   Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

You've used SQL Server to import the data which is a good thing. I would probably use data type IMAGE for the column to hold the images. You could also try the data typoe VARBINARY(MAX).
Use the Import and Export WIzard to import the data en see which datatype works.

Hope this helps you out.

Edit:
You say when you convert the attachment table you only have the names of the images. Are these names related to the images. When you still have the images you can store them in a folder and use FILESTREAM to connect to thme using SQL Server.
Using FILESTREAM enhances the database because the data of the images is no longer saved in the database, only a reference to them.

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't support multi-valued or attachment like fields. 
For more information about FILESTREAM look at this website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh461480

Comment: Thanks for your comments, still struggling with this. I'll go though the steps I'm taking. I choose MS Access as the source, SQL Native client as the destination ..connect to server .... choose the table and EDIT Mapping change the attachment fields to IMAGE or VARBINARY, go though the rest of the wizard and get the error. - Executing
Messages
Error 0xc02020c5: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed while converting column "Photos" (23) to column "Photos" (57).  The conversion returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."